# Missing guiddef.h in project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am new to Visual C++.

I am trying to use library A that in turn uses another library B. When I try to include the header of A, I get an "Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GUID'". This error is triggered in a header in library B. When I examine the line that throws the error, the issue is that the header in library B is using a definition found in Guiddef.h, which is a microsoft header.

The problem is that I can't seem to be able to add this header or to create a project that adds it.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The header is already being #included when the error message opens the guiddef.h file.  You *really* ought to post some repro code.  Be sure to `#include <windows.h>` before anything else.

Comment: I didn't post any code because I suspected that this was a problem with a configuration somewhere since one of projects using library B did include guiddef.h correctly but the second didn't. As I said, I am new to Visual C++, so I am going after the information the VS UI is giving me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what you mean by add it to a project or create one that adds it ,but when guiddef.h is on your system and your directories (in common properties) to your MSVC environment are correctly setup ,you just have to add `#include <guiddef.h>` before the including of lib-headerfiles to your cpp or h files and everything will (should) be fine.

Comment: Oh - I thought that "add this header" meant exactly this. @Hugo: Sorry for the long, winding detour you might have taken from my attempted answer...

Comment: @Hugo: @Michael: adding a header to a source\header-file does mean #include. But when it's used as adding to a project it's not clear what is meant (could be added in Source Explorer to the Header File section ?)

Comment: @Michael Burr No, thanks for the help. You helped me learn more about how VS works with C++. I normally work with C#, and the common interface can misguide one. @Edwin thanks again for providing the correct answer. I still wonder why the file is included correctly in the other project without my having to add #include <guiddef.h> but that will just have to be a mystery for right now.

Answer (score 2):

`guiddef.h` is part of the Windows SDK. If you have VS 2010 Express the SDK is not included, you'll need to download it separately.

If you're using a VS SKU that's 'above' Express, the SDK should already be installed (I'm not sure if you can deselect it or not when in stalling).  By default it'll go into:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\
```

The "Visual Studio Command Prompt" shortcuts that VS installs should set the `INCLUDE` environment variable appropriately. And a default C++ project should also have the include path setup appropriately, but it can be changed in the project's "VC++ Directories" property (you should check that).  If you have a per-project setting here that is wrong, change it there.

However, if your 'IDE-wide' VC++ Directories properties that are inherited by every (or at least most) C++ projects is messed up, follow the instructions on this blog article to fix the global VC++ Directories settings in VS 2010:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx

Specifically:

> If you open up the Property Manager view to see the property sheets associated with your project, you’ll see that one of the property sheets is named `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User`. This property sheet is actually stored in `LocalAppData`, just as `VCComponents.dat` file was, in the directory `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`. Using the property editor on the property sheet (just right-click on this property sheet node and select Properties...), you can see that you are able to make edits directly to this file. Since all projects, by default, import this property sheet, you are effectively editing the VC++ directories in the same way you were able to do before.

Comment: No, I am not using Express. I am using Premium. The header is added correctly in another project.

Comment: Yes; on this note it might be a good idea to include which version of Visual Studio you're using (express vs. the retail version) in your question.  The express version exclude things like this SDK, and the MFC, or other things that someone might assume are included as a part of visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just went ahead and included that information.

Comment: I checked the link, and I examined the VC++ directories, and they seem to be correct. But there may be something wrong with it, so I will carefully look through my installation to  see if something went wrong somewhere. Thank so much for your direction.

Comment: @Hugo: try these things, too:  Make sure "C/C++ | Preprocessor | Ignore Standard include Paths" isn't set to "Yes"; add `/showIncludes` (which is in the IDE project properties as "C/C++ | Advanced | Show Includes") - this might give you a clue about whether the build seems to be looking in the right places; look at the CL.read.1.tlog file for similar information.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (though not necessarily true) that you need to include a library as a linker dependency.  I'm assuming here that you're already using #include  (and have the correct case, with a lowercase 'g')

**My suggestion:**

1. Open up the project that has the
   header included
2. open the 'project' menu, and select
   'properties'
3. Under 'configuration properties'
   select 'linker'
4. under 'linker' select 'input'
5. take a peek at the 'additional
   dependencies' field (right at the
   top on the right hand side).  You
   may see some libraries listed there.
6. Make a note of any libraries
   included as dependencies, and repeat
   these steps in your 'broken'
   project. Add the appropriate libraries to the 'broken' project, if needeed.

You probably don't need the same dependencies in both projects, but if you do need to link a library in the borked project, you should be able to narrow down which one it is you need and include it in the dependency list.

Hope that helps, or at least doesn't steer you too far off course!

**edit:**

Actually, for some of the headers in the windows API, you might not be able to include them 'alone' (I'm not sure if guiddef.h is one of them), but they should be included as a sub-header of windows.h.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed your instructions. Both projects have exactly the same libraries, so this is not the cause. But it is good to rule this out.

Comment: Note that if you're using MSVC, then you should probably use `#pragma comment(lib, "mylibraryname.lib")` from source to ensure you don't have problems with library settings buried in some menu somewhere (and so that if you loose your build settings you don't have to spend three years screwing with it :) )

Comment: @Billy ONeal That's a great tip! I hadn't thought of that =)